# variable being passed from nowhere to geo location function

Tags: javascript

I have always had a problem with understanding veriables that get passed from thin air and are not declared anywhere, see the below script for example, i can across it when i was trying to understand the geo location API:

```
function geoFindMe() {
  var output = document.getElementById("out");

  if (!navigator.geolocation){
    output.innerHTML = "<p>Geolocation is not supported by your browser</p>";
    return;
  }

  function success(position) {
    var latitude  = position.coords.latitude;
    var longitude = position.coords.longitude;

    output.innerHTML = '<p>Latitude is ' + latitude + '° <br>Longitude is ' + longitude + '°</p>';

    var img = new Image();
    img.src = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=" + latitude + "," + longitude + "&zoom=13&size=300x300&sensor=false";

    output.appendChild(img);
  };

  function error() {
    output.innerHTML = "Unable to retrieve your location";
  };

  output.innerHTML = "<p>Locating…</p>";

  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
}
```

The above code can be seen **[HERE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/Using_geolocation)**.

Now check out this below line:

```
function success(position) {
```

Now who on earth is passing the `position` variable to success function ? this really baffles me, i have seen similar things when i use jQuery Ajax function. can somebody explain this concept of variables being passed from no-where ?

Answer (score 1):

Here:

> ```
> navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
> ```

… you pass `success` to `getCurrentPosition`.

At some point either `getCurrentPosition` or another function called by it will call `success` and pass it some arguments.

They don't come from thin air, they come from a function that your code calls. It's just that someone else wrote that function.

Comment: `At some point either getCurrentPosition or another function called by it will call success and pass it some arguments.` can you give an example ? i am still quite confused by this ...

Comment: `function getCurrentPosition(callback) { callback("here are your coordinates"); }`

Comment: I am afraid this is still not making sense ! thanks for trying though .

Answer (score 1):

Success is a [callback function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_(computer_programming)#JavaScript).

In order to understand how callback functions operate, one must understand that in JavaScript, functions are objects. If I pass function A as an argument to function B, function B can call function A internally with variables that need not be available at the time of calling function B.

Callbacks are especially important in asynchronous code, where I do not receive an answer immediately to a function immediately but want to trigger an event when I do receive the answer. In this particular case,

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
```

is function B. It expects two functions as arguments. One to call if the function succeeds and one to call if the function errors out.

The implementation of getCurrentPosition() will, if the invocation is successful, call the success callback with the an object describing the CurrentPosition you are trying to retrieve as an argument.

To explain what is happening further, here's an example:

```
function callFunctionWithOneAsFirstArg(callback) {
    callback(1);
}

callFunctionWithOneAsFirstArg(function(number) { console.log(number); });
```

In this instance, the invocation of callFunctionWithOneAsFirstArg() does not know how number is set. Nonetheless, it can rely on the fact that the library provided callFunctionWithOneAsFirstArg() will perform the expected behavior.

You might notice another example of using callbacks in your javascript is when you need to handle an external event like a click. Whenever a button is clicked, for example, you might want a certain function to be fired. Because you want to delay the invocation of your callback function, the EventListener that you created will call the callback for you when and only when the button is clicked.